# Error with "Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar"

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a deep learning algorithm in Keras with a Tensorflow backend. I am trying to do the following:

```
x = tf.reshape(theta, [-1])[K.argmax(image)]
```

Where `image` is the input and `eta` is a coordinate. I am trying to flatten theta, but I get the error

```
 Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor 'loss_42/dense_264_loss/ArgMax:0' shape=(25,) dtype=int64>
```

Comment: what's your theta shape and image shape? You cannot directly slice a tensor with a `(25,)` shape tensor.

Comment: The theta shape is 25*25 and my image shape is (1,25,25).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you want to get the theta values according to the `K.argmax(image)`. You cannot directly use fancy indexing style in the tensorflow. `tf.gather` can achieve this instead.

```py
res = tf.gather(tf.reshape(theta, [-1]), K.argmax(image))
```